# How to add Listview in NavigationView?

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer, android-recyclerview, navigationview

I have a navigation drawer in my android app. I can show a menu in navigation drawer with navigationView, but I want to show a listview or recyclerview in the drawer. I need so because drawer menu is not the same for every user. the users choose the newspapers which they want to read. for example:

- user A's listview will be like this : Washington Post, New York
  Times, Guardian, Independent.
- user B's listview : Daily Mail, Washington Post, Financial Times.

How can i add listview on navigationView?

activity_main.xml :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout >
 ...
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
   ...
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
       ...
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
    app:layout="@layout/custom_row"/>
```

menu_drawer.xml :

```
<group
    android:id="@+id/group_1"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_first_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_number_0"
        android:title="First" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_second_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_number_1"
        android:title="Second" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_third_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_number_2"
        android:title="Third" />
</group>

<group
    android:id="@+id/group_2"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_11"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_number_0"
        android:title="My Newspapers">

        <menu>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_number_0"
                android:title="@string/navigation_item_1" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/navigation_item_2"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_number_1"
                android:title="@string/navigation_item_2" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/navigation_item_3"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_number_2"
                android:title="@string/navigation_item_3" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/navigation_item_4"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_number_3"
                android:title="@string/navigation_item_4" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/navigation_item_5"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_number_4"
                android:title="@string/navigation_item_5" />

        </menu>
    </item>
</group>
```

custom_row.xml :

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/text_superhero"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingBottom="4dp"
      android:paddingLeft="16dp"
      android:paddingRight="16dp"
      android:paddingTop="4dp"
      android:text="Superhero"
      android:textColor="@color/colorTextSecondary">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `NavigationView` is nothing more than a wrapper for `RecyclerView` that populates the list from a menu XML resource and provides a Material-compliant drawer out of the box. There really isn't any special logic that makes it work in a navigation drawer.

If you want a more dynamic navigation drawer, you should simple replace the `NavigationView` in your layout XML with a `RecyclerView` and populate it like you would any other `RecyclerView`.

Comment: i replaced Navigationview with RecyclerView,  but it didn't work. the recyclerview matched all of the  screen. toolbar and another views aren't shown

Comment: Your navigation drawer is completely independent of your toolbar and your the other views on screen. Make sure you are only replacing the `NavigationView`, and that all the properties of the RecyclerView are the same as what you had before (e.g. `android:layout_width`).

Comment: i replaced just NavigationView tag with RecyclerView, didn't change the properties, just add same new properties and done! thank you.

Answer (score 11):

You can use this code, but remember you need use adapter to populate your ListView

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/nav_header_main" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:textColor="#424242"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

You have this result:

[image: screenshot]